# Jackson customized deserialize runtime exception been wrapped with JsonMappingException

Tags: java, json, exception, jackson, jackson-databind

I have a customised deserialiser, expect `CustomRuntimeException` when `id` is not `String` type, but the exception was wrapped with `JsonMappingException` in my test result. The test case works fine before I upgrade the `jackson-databind` module from `2.5.x` to `2.10.x`. But it failed with:

> `java.lang.Exception`: Unexpected exception,
> expected `<CustomRuntimeException>` but
> was `<com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException>`

after I upgraded the `jackson-databind`.

```
@Override
public Optional<String> deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser,
                                    DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException {

  if (jsonParser.getCurrentToken() != JsonToken.VALUE_STRING) {
    throw new CustomRuntimeException("Id should be String");
  }
  return Optional.ofNullable(jsonParser.getValueAsString());
}
```

The CustomRuntimeException:

```
public class CustomRuntimeException extends RuntimeException {

    public CustomRuntimeException() {
        super("Invalid argument is provided.");
    }

    public CustomRuntimeException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

Test case:

```
@Test(expected = CustomRuntimeException.class)
public void shouldThrowCustomRuntimeException() throws IOException {
  objectMapper.readValue("{ \"id\": 1245672564 }", IdSchema.class);
}
```

Stack trace:

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: id should be String (through reference chain: com.xxx["id"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:397)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:356)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.wrapAndThrow(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1714)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeWithErrorWrapping(BeanDeserializer.java:530)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeUsingPropertyBased(BeanDeserializer.java:417)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromObjectUsingNonDefault(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1287)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:326)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:159)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4218)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3214)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3182)
    at com.xxx.shouldThrowCustomRuntimeException(xxx.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.ExpectException.evaluate(ExpectException.java:19)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: com.xxx.CustomRuntimeException: id should be String
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable feature [DeserializationFeature.WRAP_EXCEPTIONS](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.10/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html#WRAP_EXCEPTIONS):

> Feature that determines whether `Jackson` code **should catch and wrap**
> **Exceptions (but never Errors!)** to add additional information about
> location (within input) of problem or not. If enabled, most exceptions
> will be caught and re-thrown (exception specifically being that
> IOExceptions may be passed as is, since they are declared as
> throwable); this can be convenient both in that all exceptions will be
> checked and declared, and so there is more contextual information.
> However, sometimes calling application may just want "raw" unchecked
> exceptions passed as is. **Feature is enabled by default**.

Example:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = JsonMapper.builder()
        .disable(DeserializationFeature.WRAP_EXCEPTIONS)
        .build();
```

Or, you can extend `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException` instead of `RuntimeException`:

```
class CustomRuntimeException extends JsonMappingException {

    public CustomRuntimeException(Closeable processor, String msg) {
        super(processor, msg);
    }

    public CustomRuntimeException(Closeable processor) {
        super(processor, "Invalid argument is provided.");
    }
}
```

and throw it this way from deserialiser:

```
if (p.getCurrentToken() != JsonToken.VALUE_STRING) {
    throw new CustomRuntimeException(p, "Id should be String");
}
```

In both cases you should see something similar to:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.celoxity.CustomRuntimeException: Id should be String
 at [Source: (File); line: 1, column: 9] (through reference chain: com.example.IdSchema["id"])
    at com.example.IdJsonDeserializer.deserialize(JsonTypeInfoApp.java:36)
    at com.example.IdJsonDeserializer.deserialize(JsonTypeInfoApp.java:31)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:129)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:288)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:151)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4202)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3070)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think in Jackson-databind 2.5 the wrap_exception also is true by default, not sure why the behavior change after upgrading to 2.10 
https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html#WRAP_EXCEPTIONS